# How can I programmatically refresh Visual Studio Solution Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, solution-explorer

How can I programmatically refresh Visual Studio Solution Explorer?

I can get a hold of the solution explorer window object, but don't know what to do with it!

```
var solutionExplorer = (UIHierarchy)DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsext_wk_SProjectWindow).Object();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you can figure out these things by recording a temporary macro, doing what you want to do, and seeing what comes out in the macro editor.

Indeed, this is a case where it's probably *only* by recording a temporary macro that you can figure out how to do this.  Here's the command to refresh the Solution Explorer:

```
DTE.Commands.Raise("{1496A755-94DE-11D0-8C3F-00C04FC2AAE2}", 222, null, null)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I used your trick (macro).  I had to add a line prior to yours to make it worked: DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer).Activate();

Comment: I had a problem with this too, until I did as joerage said (I was getting a "The Command to execute is not enabled." error). You both rock :)

Comment: I too get the same error "The Command to execute is not enabled." any solution to this?